# What is the best way to demux a publisher's Output?

Tags: swiftui, combine

I have an `ObservableObject` with a few publishers:

```swift
private class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var top3: [SearchResult] = []
    @Published var albums: [SearchResult.Album] = []
    @Published var artists: [SearchResult.Artist] = []
}
```

The endpoint is a URLSessionDataPublisher that sends a single collection of values that can be either an album or an artist (there are actually more types but I'm reducing the problem set here.) What is the best way in Combine to separate this collection out into 3 collections: `[Album]`, `[Artist]`, and an array of 3 results that can be either `Artist` or `Album`?

```swift
DatabaseRequest.Search(for: searchTerm)
    .publisher()
    // now i want to separate the collection out into [Album] and [Artist] and assign to my 3 @Published vars
    .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
    .sink { }
    .store(in: bag)
```

Comment: at the end, that means in subscriber, in your case in sink

Answer (score 0):

You are hitting a bit of a (common) fallacy that Combine is responsible for passing the changed data in SwiftUI. It isn't. The only thing Combine is doing here is providing the content-less message that *some* data has changed, and then the SwiftUI components that are using the relevant model object go and look for their data.

The data transfer in SwiftUI is entirely using Binding, which are essentially `get` and `set` closures under the covers.

So you don't really need to worry about demuxing a combine stream - and there isn't one that has "one" of these kinds of data in it. Combine would have trouble with that since it's strongly typed for both Output type and Failure type.

There's a bit more written about this in [Using Combine](https://gum.co/usingcombine) under the chapter 
[SwiftUI and Combine](https://heckj.github.io/swiftui-notes/#swiftui-and-combine) *(chapter link to the free HTML version)*